# How to do ultra fast batchimport in orientdb from csv files?

Tags: orientdb

We are evaluating graph databases to store our networked communication data and zeroed upon neo4j and orientdb. 
Is there a batch importer tool or script for orient similar to what neo4j has? I was able to import a csv files with150M relationships and 18M nodes in under 25 mins for neo4j. Reading the documentation on orientdb site, looks like I need to use the ETL feature by modifying an json file to be able to do the import. Is there no other simpler and faster way to do the import from csv files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OrientDB ETL is pretty easy. Look at: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Import-from-CSV-to-a-Graph.html. Just create your json with the ETL steps and it's done.